linking errors in yocto poky cross-compiling
I can not figure out the following linking errors when I tried to build TI graphics with yocto. They are general compiling errors, I have added link path /home/kaijun/Projects/build/tmp/work/beagleboard-poky-linux-gnueabi/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/rootfs/usr/lib where Scrt1.o and crti.o are
../arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/12.2.0/ld: cannot find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory
../arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/12.2.0/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
and /home/kaijun/Projects/build/tmp/work/beagleboard-poky-linux-gnueabi/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-poky-linux-gnueabihf/12.2.0 where crtbeginS.o is
../arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/12.2.0/ld: cannot find crtbeginS.o: No such file or directory
Thanks for any ideas!
